# AppleScript to paste text from clipboard into a file

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I thought this would be easy.  The Google makes me think otherwise.

What I want is a poor man's inter-OS clipboard.  Everything I looked at on the net is either not free, no app this simple should cost anybody anything, or isn't compatible with local linux installs or Windows or some such.

In the best solution a right mouse action would be added to "cut", "copy" and "paste" named something like "copy to file".  The file might or might not exist but would have a fixed name and be on a shared disk.

I guess I'd need a second right mouse action "Paste from file" to complement the "copy to file".

So, would some one show me how to have an AppleScript or, maybe, Automator, take the current text contents of the clipboard and paste into an existing file, overwriting any
 existing contents of the file?

OS/X Snow Leopard

Thanks.

Comment: What type of file are you copying the text from?

Comment: Filetype is indeterminate.  I realize all I can reliably extract is text and am assuming that the past to flat file action  will just paste the text part of anything on the clipboard.  Do I need additional code to make sure the text is just flat text?

Comment: @fanaugen Never mind.  The answers to both questions is "yes".  Now, how do I tie these applets to pretty much all of the mouse menus?

Comment: @WesMiller see edit to my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how to have an AppleScript […], take the current text contents of the clipboard and paste into an existing file, overwriting any existing contents of the file

AppleScript code:

```
do shell script "pbpaste > /path/to/your/clipboard-file.txt"
```

In order to read text from the file back into the clipboard, use

```
do shell script "cat /path/to/your/clipboard-file.txt | pbcopy"
```

For documentation, see [`man pbpaste`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/pbpaste.1.html)

EDIT: Now, to convert the AppleScript into a Mac OS X **Service**, which will appear in the "Services" group of every context menu (at right-click / CTRL+click on any text), you can use Automator, as described in [this tutorial](http://www.automatedworkflows.com/2011/05/22/creating-applescript-services-in-mac-os-x/).

Comment: To @fanaugen Enter this in the script editor?  Make it an app?

Comment: How to write out into a file in the current working directory? (For a variable path situation.)

Comment: @Zuooo I’m not sure AppleScript has the concept of a current working directory, but if you’re running pbpaste in the shell, you can simply pipe the output into a file without a path like this:

`pbpaste > from_clipboard.txt`

Comment: It reported error `Read-only file system` if no path provided. @fanaugen